# What is the fastest way to change the order of elements in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, performance

I have a first ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Move> moves = new ArrayList<>();
```

and want to reorder the elements randomly into a second one:

```
ArrayList<Move> randomMoves = new ArrayList<>();
```

Normally I do:

```
    while (randomMoves.size() < moves.size()) {
    
        int index = (int) (Math.random() * moves.size());

        while (randomMoves.contains(moves.get(index))) {

            index = (int) (Math.random() * moves.size());
        }
        
        randomMoves.add(moves.get(index));
    }
```

but it goes without saying that this is a performance disaster
(the last elements will take time to get chosen randomly)...

normally this is not so much of an issue,
but this code is going to be executed in a time-critical part of the application
and I don't have a lot experience with time-critical code...

enlighten me :)

S.

Comment: Just copy everything then use `Collections.shuffle`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Collections.shuffle(List<?> list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) to shuffle the elements in the `list`.

```
ArrayList<Move> randomMoves = new ArrayList<>(moves);
Collections.shuffle(randomMoves);
```

The first line of the code [creates an `ArrayList<Move> randomMoves` containing the elements of `moves`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) and the second line of the code shuffles the elements in `randomMoves`.